# Images inside posts re-sized gradually to be in zeros width and height in android browser

Tags: javascript, android, css

I've got many reports from Android visitors to [my blog](http://ar.swiftbraille.com/blog/facebook-automatic-alternative-text/) said that when they are browsing any post from my blog, the images inside the posts get re-sized gradually to be hidden completely (width and height like be zeros, just the shadow of the image is visible).

I've tested that and I confirm the issue in android browser and Facebook browser as well, but Google Chrome shows everything OK.

I don't know what is causing this problem, JavaScript or CSS problem? I'm using a bootstrap css code for images for responsiveness on mobile devices.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this line did the problem:

```
img {box-sizing:border-box};
```

I removed it and it works in Android browser!